# Amiga-looking keyboard for PC

Tags: amiga, keyboards

I would like to use an Amiga-looking keyboard on my PC.  (I prefer not to use my old original A2000 keyboard with an [adapter](http://ezhid.sourceforge.net/amikbd.html), partly because it lacks many keys present on modern 105-key keyboards, and partly because it's not localized.)

So far the best option I've found is to buy a [WASD custom keyboard](http://www.wasdkeyboards.com/) with the keys appropriately painted white or grey. Unfortunately, a white or beige base is not available, only a black one.

Are there other options?

Comment: You want something that doesn't exist.  Commodore never made an Amiga keyboard with the modern 105-key features.  If you want a keyboard that "sorta" looks like an Amiga then you are stuck with a modern keyboard with the same color scheme.  The WASD custom keyboard has an option of an "A" key for the OS key.  That's about as close as you're going to get.

Comment: @cbmeeks I know that, basically I wrote all of this on my question.  I'd like to know if a custom WASD keyboard is the closest I can get or if someone made an Amiga-looking keyboard usable on PCs.

Comment: I actually looked into this a while back myself.  I was going to build a USB to Amiga 1000 keyboard converter because you can't find A1000 keyboards without buying another A1000.  In my search, I came across the WASD and "A" key.  From everything I could find, that was your best option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hi we've started this project for new Amiga-style keyboards and mice here: https://www.simulant.uk/input/

Comment: Actually, I think I was too harsh earlier; you've disclosed your affiliation and made an effort to answer the question, and I overreacted. :-/ Sorry about that. Reading the [tour] and [answer] would be good – I take it you've already read [How to not be a spammer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).

Comment: Elaborating on this answer would be extremely useful – how, exactly, does this answer the question? Pictures, a description and a direct link would be preferable to just linking to the main page.

Comment: That looked like a neat project.  Sad to hear it was cancelled because the Kickstarter campaign did not get enough funds.  Good luck for next time and +1 as an encouragement.

Comment: I registered my interest anyway. Hope something comes of it.

Answer (score 9):

There is the X500 Evo mechanical keyboard. Unfortunately, this was produced for an X500 Kickstarter project, which is an A500 style computer case. It is no longer produced.

You can see it on YouTube:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e-DdAf7sOaY

The project owner says that the keys are standard Cherry MX and are still available.

Answer (score 5):

Individual Computers in Germany makes [Amiga Keyboard stickers](https://icomp.de/shop-icomp/en/shop/product/amiga-keyboard-sticker.html). They seem to be available in black only (at least I think that's black), but in various languages.

Answer (score 2):

Amiga on the Lake has new A500/1200 keyboard with USB support:

https://amigaonthelake.com/new-a500-replacement-keyboard-with-full-set-of-amiga-keycaps/

To get this to work on a non-Amiga, you can use the USB support, but would need to add a case for it.